# How to redirect user in service layer in SOA after authentication?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm building a web application and using SOA. Now, whenever a user sends anything to database, he needs an authentication (security token I built). If the token was changed, the application should kick the user out. First of all, I make an AJAX  call to out chat in the database, then when it comes to service layer, this is where I test the token in service layer:

```
function putChat($d,$ip,$token){
///check security
//if the user should be here
if(checkToken($token,$ip,$user_id)){
     echo putChatData($message,$room,$user_id);   
}
//if not, send false back to kick him out
else{
    header('Location: logout.php');
}
```

}

My problem is that this header thing doesn't work in the service layer at all, I tried to put it in the top and echo nothing before that but it didn't work. What should I do?